# Price calculations displaying 2 Currencies in WooCommerce Checkout Subtotal &Total line

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

```
ETH 5 ($ 3.753,65)
```

I want to show two currencies in checkout Subtotal & Totals in woocommerce. I'm guessing i'm using the wrong hook?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DV7S.png)

```
// Convert to USD
function convert_price_cart( $price ){
$convertion_rate = 780.730022;
$new_price = $price * $convertion_rate;
return number_format($new_price, 2, '.', '');
}

add_filter( 'wc_price', 'my_custom_price_format', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_price_format( $formatted_price, $price, $args ) {

// The currency conversion custom calculation function
$price_usd = convert_price_cart($price);

// the currency symbol for US dollars
$currency = 'USD';
$currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency );
$price_usd = $currency_symbol.$price_usd; // adding currency symbol

// The USD formatted price
$formatted_price_usd = "<span class='price-usd'> ($price_usd)</span>";

// Return both formatted currencies
return $formatted_price . $formatted_price_usd;
}
```

Is there anybody could help me with this situation.